# How to query List<Int> on Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

How can I filter out the RealmFilter.objectIds that has a given Int?

```
func delete(ids: [Int]) {
   let filterResultsToDelete = realm.objects(CRMRealmFilterResult.self).filter("ANY objectIds IN %@",ids)
//Crashes
}


class RealmFilterResult : Object {
    @objc dynamic var filterId: Int = 0
    let objectIds = List<Int>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "filterId"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be at all what you want but it was a good exercise. Maybe this will help.

Let me re-state what I think you're asking: You've got a series of objects that each have a List property of Int's and you want to be able to query for all objects that have a particular int in their list

Using a more real-world example, suppose we have a list of teams and we keep a list of game scores (a list) within each team

```
class TeamObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var object_id = NSUUID().uuidString

    let scoreList = List<ScoreObject>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "object_id"
    }
}
```

and we have a score object that stores a score as an Int (and maybe other details like who they played or the date)

```
class ScoreObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var score = 0
    let teamsWithScores = LinkingObjects(fromType: TeamObject.self, property: "scoreList")
}
```

For simplicity, let's create three scores and two teams and give each team two scores in their list.

```
let score1 = ScoreObject()
score1.score = 1
let score2 = ScoreObject()
score2.score = 2
let score3 = ScoreObject()
score3.score = 3

let t1 = TeamObject()
t1.scoreList.append(score1)
t1.scoreList.append(score3)

let t2 = TeamObject()
t2.scoreList.append(score2)
t2.scoreList.append(score3)
```

and write them to realm

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(t1)
    realm.add(t2)
}
```

from there, we can get any team that has a score of 1, which solves the question of getting the objects that have a list that contain a given int.

```
let results = realm.objects(ScoreObject.self).filter("score IN %@", [1])
if results.count > 0 {
    for aScore in results {
        let teamsWithThisScore = aScore.teamsWithScores
        for team in teamsWithThisScore {
            print("score: \(aScore.score)")
            print("     id: \(team.object_id)")
        }
    }
} else {
    print("no teams with those scores")
}
```

you can expand on this to get teams (object) that have several scores (ints)

```
let results = realm.objects(ScoreObject.self).filter("score IN %@", [1,3])
```

As I said, it may be off base but it does provide a solution in a more object oriented way.

Answer (score 0):

Querying `List` of primitives (i.e. non `Object` subclasses, like `Int` in your case) is not yet supported by Realm.

You can follow the status of this on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5334).