# How to use NSPredicate for whether a List of Int contains a Int number?

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

I got a Realm model `Person` who has a tag property.

```
let tags = List<Int>()
```

Now, I would like to perform a search like this

```
realm.objects(Person.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "\(tagID) IN tags"))
// "0 IN tags"
```

Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid value', reason:
 'Expected object of type (null) for property 'tags' on object of type
 'Person', but received: 0'
```

Comment: Querying a List of primitives is not supported. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54133497/4667835) Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in David's comment, you cannot filter on a list of primitives.

**EDIT:** Release 10.7 added support for filters/queries as well as aggregate functions on primitives so the below info is no longer completely valid. However, it's still something to be aware of.

You can only filter on List's that contain Realm Objects. However, there are other solutions.

Here we get all of the Realm objects and filter the objects using Swift. In this case we want all of the persons that have a tag = 7.

```
let personResults = realm.objects(PersonClass.self)
let persons = personResults.filter { $0.tags.firstIndex(of: 7) != nil }
    
for person in persons {
    print(person.name)
}
```

for another option, see the answer at the link in @DávidPásztor comment.

Comment: I know this method, but it will load all data to memory immediately, right? So, alternatively, I can create a Tag model to store all tags, and then I can filter on List contain specific tag since Tag now is a subclass of Object.

Comment: @JsW Well, yes, kinda. Realm objects are lazily loaded so they wouldn't actually be or stay in memory until they are accessed. But it may or may not be relevant. So for example; if you have a couple hundred users or can limit your results using a filter, that would be low memory impact. The alternate, as suggested in the link, is to create a Tag object. However, the downside of that is you have another object Realm is managing and may end up with 500 Tag objects with the value of 2, and all of that mess would be stored in Realm.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I thought. I need to make a trade-off. Because I'm using Reasults<ModelType>  as data source type everywhere, it would be troublesome to make them compatible. Thanks, man.